# How to get the number of apps ranking on the App Store for a given search term?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-api

Is it possible to get the number of apps ranking on the App Store for a given term by performing just one request?

I've been playing with various (Apple) APIs (both official and undocumented), but all of them use pagination (using `limit` and `offset`). While this allows me to get the (total) number of results, it's inefficient as I need to execute multiple requests.

Various tools like App Radar and Appfigures show this metric. Either they use an unknown (to me) API, or are using pagination to get it.

Hoping you're able to help me out with this. Thanks.